# Haskell error in VScode: "Error during extended interface generation"

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, intermittent

Fairly new to Haskell and VScode.  First line of code gives error (when I highlight over it)

"Error during extended interface generationC:\Users\Curtis\AppData\Local\ghcide\main-da39...\ext5545: renameFile:renamePath:MoveFileEx "\\?\C:\Users\Curtis\AppData\Local\ghcide\main-da39...\ext5545" Just "\\?\C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\ghcide\main-da39...\Main.hie": permission denied (Access is denied.)extended interface generation"

If I add extra blank lines at the end the error will disappear and reappear randomly.  Sometimes going away for the exact same written code.  The code I have is

```
replicate' :: (Integral n) => n-> b-> [b]
replicate' n b
    | n<0 = error "can't replicate a negative number"
    | n<=0 = []
    | True = b:replicate' (n-1) b  

take' :: (Integral n) => n -> [b] -> [b]
take' n list
    | n<=0 = []
    | length list==0 = []
    | True = x:(take' (n-1) xs)
    where (x:xs)= list

takess' :: b->b
takess' b =b

fin = 5
```

But since it is intermittent based off the number of lines I am dubious how replicable it will be.

The code sometimes complies with error, other-times not (have trouble replicating this though so it may always compile).

Any advice on what the error is, how to make it go and stay away, or how to make it stop saying there is an error when there isn't would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks like a file permission issue, or since this is Windows, perhaps the file is in use and thus can not be acessed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am pretty sure I never had that file open, I had tried closing and reopening all the associated files/programs and that didn't work, but I tried it again just now and I can't replicate it.  Hopefully it sticks, but I am dubious. Thanks regardless!